# How I access results from a db query in Koa?

Tags: node.js, koa, bookshelf.js

I'm new in Node, Koa and web development, I'm trying to send data from a query to the template. I'm using [Bookshelfjs](http://bookshelfjs.org/) as ORM.

```
module.exports = {

    /** Get user info by id */
    getId: function * getId (next) {

        // var user = { username: 'lucas', passowrd: 'lucas' };

        userMng.findById(this.params.id, (err, user) => {

            this.body = yield this.render('id', {
                title: 'Show detailes about item: ' + this.params.id,
                data: user
            });

        });

        yield next;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `findById`, and where does it come from? I can't find a reference to that method in bookshelfjs. And for that matter, what is `userMng`? Is that a bookshelf model?

Comment: srry, look at this [module](http://pastebin.com/Krus36a8)

Comment: Got it. Just yield `User.where('uid', id).fetch()` inside koa, and you'll get a `user` back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to use their `Promise` interface. I'm not sure what `findById` is, so I'll give you an example modified from their documentation.

```
module.exports = {

    /** Get user info by id */
    getId: function * getId (next) {

        // assume User is a bookshelf model.
        // probably userMng in your case, but it's hard to say without more code.
        let user = yield User.where('id', this.params.id).fetch();

        this.body = yield this.render('id', {
            title: 'Show detailes about item: ' + this.params.id,
            data: user
        });

        yield next;
    }
};
```